# Azure management API without certificate

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have a Java application running on Azure inside a VM. Let say I have 10 VMs like this one.
I'd like to get details about other virtual machines running within the same cloud service.

I managed to do that using certificates but I don't like this solution as each VMs has locally a certificate which might stolen if a hacker get an access to my machine.

I would love not having to provide such a certificate or any authentication as soon as my VM is running inside Azure platform.

I can do exactly the same with Google Compute Engine. If you want to access management APIs on GCE, you don't need to provide anything. I guess that as soon you run a GET request to http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/ `metadata` knows exactly "who" is doing the request using IP Address or whatever.

Is it doable on Azure?

Thanks!

Comment: If a hacker gets access to your machine you'll have bigger issues than them stealing your management certificate.  GCE will still be requiring authorisation on those calls otherwise I would be extremely concerned about their architecture.  Mutual authentication with certificates is really the only option you have without building some form of proxy service you call.

Comment: Let say I have a FTP service on my VM. But with a bad configuration so an anonymous user can read my file. I'm really concerned by that. There are more risks IMHO. Connecting locally using SSH is a way more complicated. So I would say it's more secure.

Comment: GCE instances metadata server is exclusive to them. That's why instances don't require authentication to query their metadata servers. Also, GCE instances uses service accounts set up during their creation to perform authentication requiring operations by default.

Comment: @Antonio exactly. I'd love something similar on azure. A private server like `https://private.non.existing.domain/`instead of `https://management.core.windows.net/`